# Check from Constructor if function in child class exists?

Tags: php, oop

is it possible to do something like this in PHP 5.2.1?

```
abstract class Test
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     if (function_exists('init')):
        $this->init();
  }
}
```

If i try this, the function on the subclass is not called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`method_exists`](http://php.net/method_exists) to see if an object has a method with a given name. However, this doesn't let you test what arguments the method takes. Since you're defining an abstract class, simply make the desired method an abstract method.

```
abstract class Test {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }
    abstract protected function init();
}
```

Just be careful you don't call `init` more than once, and child classes invoke their parents' constructors.

Answer (score 0):

"something like" WHAT exactly?

Anyway, your syntax is totally wrong...

```
  public function __construct()
  {
     if (function_exists('init')
     {
        $this->init();
     }
  }
```